# Image is not uploading in PHP. Showing my own defined error

Tags: php, mysql, session, file-upload

I am trying to upload image but getting my own exception :

> **Image is not valid, please select a proper image.**

I reviewed my code and researched on google and in stackoverflow as well. But did not get any proper solution. It is my code given below for uploading image
.

## Code :

```
$fetchName = "SELECT FirstNameMiddleName, LastName FROM mmb WHERE UserId = ".$_SESSION['UserId'];
            $fetchNameFire = mysqli_query($conn, $fetchName);
            $resultName = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetchNameFire);
             $filename = $_FILES["aadhaarphoto"]["name"]."_".$_SESSION['UserId']."_".$resultName['FirstNameMiddleName']."_".$resultName['LastName'];
             $tempname = $_FILES["aadhaarphoto"]["tmp_name"];

             $folder = "AadhaarCards/".$filename;

             //====================================================
             $allowedExtension = array('jpg','png','gif','JPG','PNG','GIF');
             $ext = pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
             //====================================================
             if(!in_array($ext,$allowedExtension))
             {
                 //echo mysqli_error($conn);
                 echo 'Image is not valid, please select a proper image';
             }
             else
             {
                 $updateUser = "UPDATE mmb SET Address = '$UserAddress', DOB = '$UserDOB', Phone = '$UserPhone', Whatsapp = '$UserWhatsapp', AadhaarCardNo = '$UserAadhaarNo', AadhaarCardPhoto = '$folder' WHERE UserId = ".$_SESSION['UserId'];
                 $updateUserFire = mysqli_query($conn, $updateUser);
                 if($updateUserFire)
                 {
                     move_uploaded_file($tempname, $folder);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     echo mysqli_error($conn);
                 }
             }
```

Comment: Your script is at risk for [SQL Injection Attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/). Use [prepared statements](https://bobby-tables.com/php).

Comment: Whats the actual value of $ext?

Comment: $ext = pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

Comment: Yea I can see that in the code. Dump the value out to see what it actually is.

Comment: PNG_1_Ankita_Yadav

Comment: Looks like it's working then. That's not in your list.

Comment: What to do next then ?

Comment: which list your are talking about ?

Comment: The list $allowedExtension .

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are appending things on to the end of the file name.

```
$filename = $_FILES["aadhaarphoto"]["name"]."_".$_SESSION['UserId']."_".$resultName['FirstNameMiddleName']."_".$resultName['LastName'];
```

So if the file name was "image.jpg" it would become something like "image.jpg_123_John_Doe".  The file extension is now "jpg_123_John_Doe", which is not on your list.

If you change your code like this it should work.

```
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES["aadhaarphoto"]["name"],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```